# Applying multiple validations to a field using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to check if a field in an incoming request body contains only a list of predefined integers.

for example, given: `valid_values=[2, 3, 8]`

`[2, 8]` should pass the validation and [`4, 8]` or `['2', 8]` should raise a validation error.

First I tried using `serializers.ChoiceField()` but it didn't raise any validation errors for `['2', 8]`.

also I have tried chaining validators but apparently it's not supported in Django REST framework. so this raised a TypeError:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    valid_rules = [2, 3, 8]
    tags = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField().ChoiceField(valid_rules))
```

and I didn't found anything on the documentation either.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validation method and check if all tags are in your valid values list:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    tags = serializers.ListField()

    def validate_tags(self, value):
        valid_values = [2, 3, 8]
        if not all(tag in valid_values for tag in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Tags contain invalid values")
        return data
```

Comment: Thank you @Marco, I'm new to Django and didn't realize that by using `serializers.ListField(child=serializers.ChoiceField(valid_values))` the serializer will convert `['2', 8]` to `[2, 8]` and that's why it wouldn't raise any validation errors. so I ended up using just that.

Comment: Tbh it's kind of a let down that smth so simple needs custom function implementation in Django. I'm coming from a Node.js background and doing smth like this was MUCH MORE straight forward using [Yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup)